# What is the output that the program trying to achieve

Tags: c, fork

I know about the fork(), dup2 calls but I cannot infer the output of the program.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int fds[2];

    char *argv1[] = { "ls", "-l","usr/bin", NULL};
    char *argv2[] = {"more", NULL};

    pipe(fds);

    pid1=fork();
    if(!pid1){
        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[1]);
        execvp(argv1[0],argv1);
    }

    pid2=fork();
    if(!pid2){
        close(fds[1]);
        dup2(fds[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        execvp(argv1[0],argv2);
    }

    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
    waitpid(pid2,NULL,0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Also what would happen if i experiment and mistakenly press pid1 instead of pid2 at the waitpid call in the end.

Comment: run it and see.

Comment: more: write errorls: cannot access 'usr/bin': Bad file descriptor

Comment: change that to `"/usr/bin"`. If you don't have access to read that directory or something, change it to one that you can read.

Comment: Sure, but im still not sure what this program is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally, the program is running the shell pipeline

```
ls -l usr/bin | more
```

In practice, the connections to `more` are mishandled (using copy-and-paste is dangerous if you don't make all the necessary changes). It connects the read end of the pipe to the standard output of `more`, which is simply broken. It also runs `ls` a second time (passing `argv1[0]` to `execvp()` instead of `argv2[0]`) but tells `ls` that its name is `more`.  It also doesn't believe `execvp()` can fail — but it can.

With those minimal fixes in place (the program doesn't include `<stdio.h>` so there is no error reporting), you get something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int fds[2];

    char *argv1[] = { "ls", "-l", "usr/bin", NULL };
    char *argv2[] = { "more", NULL };

    pipe(fds);

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[1]);
        execvp(argv1[0], argv1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        close(fds[1]);
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        execvp(argv2[0], argv2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I called the program `pipe31` (created from `pipe31.c`) and got the sample output:

```
$ pipe31
ls: usr/bin: No such file or directory
$ mkdir -p usr/bin
$ random -n 15 1000 9999 > usr/bin/polyglot
$ pipe31
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  75 Dec  8 22:07 polyglot
$
```

When invoked as shown, the local `random` program creates 15 random numbers between 1000 and 9999, each on its own line — corresponding to 75 bytes in the file.  The outputs were piped via `more`, but it is hard to spot that in a web browser.

As to your proposed experimentation — experiment away — you won't cause harm. What you see will depend on the size of the directory you're working in, and the size of your terminal window.  However, if the output from `ls -l` is big enough (but not too big), then you'd get a shell prompt in the middle of your `ls` listing, and you'd have `more` showing data and waiting to read a newline.  There could potentially be a competition between the shell and `more` for the following inputs which could get interesting.  That assumes you fix the problems identified in the rest of the answer before experimenting.

Comment: if the first child process experiences a runtime error, what will happen to the rror message? can the user page back to the error message?

Comment: The error message is written to standard error (assuming it is a competently written program, like `ls`), and not be piped to `more`.  The code doesn't modify standard error, so it continues to go to the terminal (unless redirected).  That's what happened when I didn't have a subdirectory `usr/bin` under my current directory in the first sample run.  (I hope that the person who wrote the code wasn't expecting to run their program from the root `/` directory — that could be a major security problem. Most likely, though, `usr/bin` is just a typo for `/usr/bin`.  I didn't fix it, though.)